# Spooldir source stop processing

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2, flume, flume-ng

I have a distant server which generate files. The server push files each 15 min to hadoop cluster. These files are stored into a specific directory. We used flume to read files from local directory and send them to HDFS. However, SpoolDir is The suitable to process data.

The problem is flume shut down processing while the file is written into the directory.
I don't know how to make `flume spooldir wait` for a complete write of file , then process it. 
Or how to block reading the file until it completly written, using a script shell or processor .

Someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Set pollDelay property for spool source. 
Spool dir source polls for new file at specific interval in the given directory.
By default value is 500ms.
Which is too fast for many systems so you should configure it accordingly.